# Adding UserControl dynammiclly to a panel on buttonClick

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my form  I have a button and I want to add a user control to a panel each time it's clicked:

```
public partial class AddInstanceForm : MetroForm
{          
      private List<Material> material { get; set; }
      public AddInstanceForm()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      // get data from db for mycombobox which exit in MaterilControl
      private void AddInstanceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          using(DBContext db=new DBContext())
          {
              material = db.Materials.ToList();
          }
      }

      // This Attached to button click
      private void anotherMaterial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {         
          MaterialControl mc = new MaterialControl(material);
          this.SuspendLayout();

          panel1.Controls.Add(mc);     

          //EDIT
          this.Invalidate();
          this.Update();

          this.ResumeLayout(false);
      }
}
```

The problem is that just one user control is added to the panel, no matter how many times the button is clicked:

```
public partial class MaterialControl : UserControl
{
      private MaterialView _material;
      private List<Material> MaterialboData { get; set; }
      public MaterialView Material
      {
          get 
          {
              _material.Name=MaterialName.Text;
              _material.Quntity = MaterialQu.Text;
              _material.MaterialID = Convert.ToInt32(MaterialName.ValueMember);
              return _material;
          }
          set 
          {
              MaterialName.Text=value.Name;
              MaterialQu.Text = value.Quntity;
              MaterialName.ValueMember = Convert.ToString(_material.MaterialID);
          }
      }

      public MaterialControl(List<Material> Data)
      {
          _material = new MaterialView();
          this.MaterialboData = new List<Material>();
          this.MaterialboData = Data;
          InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

Comment: Try calling Invalidate() after drawing the control.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding them with a new top position, if you have a panel dedicated just for these controls you could use the Dock Top instead and this would let the panel automatically layout the controls for you.

Comment: Also, what are the settings of the panel1?  Is it possible that panel one is only the size of the first Item and the other items are all just being added outside the viewable area of Panel1?  Try adding a panel1.Height += 10 in the loop.

Comment: When you step through it in the debugger, is the Z order different for each?